# Where is Artifactory OSS repository? Can not find the official repository's code

Tags: artifactory

I've tried to find and failed to succeed. Where is the repository of JFrog's Artifactory? There is no official Github repository of this. I've found the Nexus repository: https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public, but not Artifactory's.

I'd like to see the code of the Artifactory project, but even though it is considered as an OSS,I can not find the code.

Comment: https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/bintray-artifactory/org/artifactory/oss/jfrog-artifactory-oss/ -- Not everyone uses GitHub.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I meant where is the *code*? This is not the code. These are the binaries...

Comment: [It has source code too.](https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/bintray-artifactory/org/artifactory/oss/jfrog-artifactory-oss/7.31.10/) Look carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the officcal link for JFrog OSS version. You may choose according to your type of installation.
https://jfrog.com/community/download-artifactory-oss/
For all the previous versions, please visit the below link.
https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/bintray-artifactory/org/artifactory/oss/jfrog-artifactory-oss/

Comment: This is not the code. These are the binaries...

Comment: For few of the versions source code is available. Below is a link for version 7.10.2. 
https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/bintray-artifactory/org/artifactory/oss/jfrog-artifactory-oss/7.10.2/